# Content for textgroup views is not allowed for translation because of its text format

Tags: 7, views

I have this problem with a view's header. I am allowed to enter a translation but the translated text is not rendered when the view is displayed in that language.

I have the following warning in the Views interface.

> content for textgroup views is not allowed for translation because of its text format

I read other posts suggesting to visit *Configuration » Regional and language » Multilingual settings* and verify the text format is selected. These posts were addressing the problem for blocks and they didn't solve my problem.

Any similar experience or solution?

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem, then found a solution. I'll show you the details with screenshots.

1. First enable [Internationalization Views (i18nviews)](http://drupal.org/project/i18nviews).
2. Create your custom view. For example, I'll simply list the nodes related to Article content type.
3. Add a header:

   1. Click on "add" next to Header section
      [image: Header - add]
   2. Add *"Global: Text area"*
      [image: Global: Text area]
   3. Type your header text, and select your input format. Please note that I selected *"Filtered HTML"* here!
      [image: header text]
   4. Click Apply
4. After saving the view, you'll see notice, telling that this header text can not be translated, so in my case:
   *"The string `views:list_articles:default:header:views:area:content` for textgroup `views` is not allowed for translation because of its text format."*
   [image: Views - translation notice for the header; The string <code>views:list_articles:default:header:views:area:content</code> for textgroup <code>views</code> is not allowed for translation because of its text format.]
5. Go to `admin/config/regional/i18n/strings` (Home » Administration » Configuration » Regional and language » Multilingual settings » Strings)
6. Check the appropriate text format you used above, when adding a header text, it must be the same - so in my case, it's *"Filtered HTML"* -, and then click *Save configuration*.
   [image: admin/config/regional/i18n/strings - checking the appropriate input format]
7. Now go back to your custom view, and on the right dropdown menu, click **"translate view"**:
   [image: translate view]
8. Now you'll see this:
   [image: translate view 2]
9. Click on one of the *"**translate**"* links. After that, you'll see the following screen, and a message that the appropriate string for the header text translation has been created - which means from now on, you can translate it!
   [image: Created string for text group views]
10. Scroll down to the appropriate header text, and translate it:
    [image: header text to be translated]
11. [After translating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQNjg.png), click on "Save translation".
12. On the following screen, [you can see that some translations have been saved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfxGF.png).
13. Now when switching to the other language, you'll see that the header text is translated! You are READY!
    [image: Views header text is already translated]

Comment: I know I'm very late with this, but this doesn't seem to work. When adding the translations everything is fine and looks good but if you change the original (in my case english) content, all other languages get updated with the english text and you have to go through them one by one again to change them back to their own language.

Comment: @Sk8erPeter Thank you very much. It works great with Views 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

**This helps for webforms:**

Content --> Webforms --> Formname --> Edit --> Tab "Webform" --> Form settings --> (scroll down) Section "Preview Page"

- Activate in section "Preview Page" the checkbox "enable preview page"
- Set Textformat to "Plain text"
- Save configuration
- Open again section "Preview Page" and **deactivate** the checkbox "enable preview page"
- Save configuration