# "Global: Custom text" field translation

Tags: 7, views, i18n-l10n

Is it possible to translate this type of view field, Or use `t()` in this field for single words?

I'm using the [Internationalization](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) and the [Internationalization Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18nviews) modules, but I can't translate these fields.

Comment: Yes, check @Sk8erPeter reply on https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37673 or you can create a field specific template file as mentioned in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/106396 and use `t()` while printing output.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8 and 9, use `t` ( or `trans`) filter in twig element in your Global: Custom text”.

for example, create a `Global: custom text` field and paste

```
 {{ 'this text will be available in translate interface'|t }}
```

Ref for reading more: https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/filters-modifying-variables-in-twig-templates